# JSF/AJAX Dynamic Menu - 404 issue

Tags: ajax, jsf, http-status-code-404

I am trying to make a dynamic menu such that when something is selected in the first selector, the second one is populated from the database based on the selection in the first one. Here is the .xhtml:

```
<f:view>
        <h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="seasonSelector" value ="#{selector_bean.season}">
       <f:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{selector_bean.genEvents}" 
             execute="seasonSelector" render="eventSelector" />
        <f:selectItems   value ="#{selector_bean.seasons}" var ="s"
                       itemLabel="#{s.getRange()}"
                       itemValue="#{s}"></f:selectItems>    
    </h:selectOneMenu>


    <h:selectOneMenu id="eventSelector">
        <f:selectItems   value ="#{selector_bean.events}" var ="e"
                       itemLabel="#{e.event_Name}"
                       itemValue="#{e}"></f:selectItems>    
    </h:selectOneMenu>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>
```

Here is the bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "selector_bean")
@Stateless
public class selector_bean implements Serializable{
    @EJB
    SeasonFacade sf;
    @EJB
    EventFacade ef;
    @EJB
    WrestlerFacade wf;

    private Season season;
    private Event event;
    private List<Event> events;
    private Match match;
    private Wrestler wrestler;

    public List<Season> getSeasons(){
        return sf.findAll();
    }

    public void genEvents(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
        events = (ef.findBySeason(season));
    }

// setters and getters after this
```

When I change the value of the first selectOneMenu, a popup box appears with this message:

```
httpError: There was an error communicating with the server, status: 404
```

I am new to both JSF and AJAX so feel free to tear me apart if I am doing it wrong. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Seems you've a wrong perception of what happens here, sadly. We don't tear apart ;). We're here to help. Just ask luiggi, he'll tell ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@ManagedBean` is behaving as an EJB with the `@Stateless` annotation. Remove it and instead set the scope of your bean to `@ViewScoped`:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "selectorBean")
@ViewScoped
public class SelectorBean implements Serializable{
    //your implementation...
}
```

Also, make sure to follow the [JavaBean naming conventions](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf). I've changed the name of your class to start with capital letter.

Comment: Another disobedience of Java naming conventions is `_bean` part ;)